# Figures don't appear where they should

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm trying to include a couple of figures in a LaTeX document, but the images appear in other place than expected. Here is the code:

```
\subsubsection{Dónde se utiliza}

Por su gran versatilidad y la gran cantidad de librerías y módulos externos que posee, Python es un lenguaje ampliamente utilizado en ámbitos tales como la \textbf{Inteligencia Artificial}, el \textbf{Big Data}, \textbf{Frameworks de pruebas}, y \textbf{Desarrollo Web}, entre otras muchas cosas.\\

Recientemente Stack Overflow, la mayor comunidad de programadores del mundo, en la que se resuelven dudas y se debate sobre distintos aspectos de la informática, ha elaborado un informe sobre los lenguajes más consultados en su sitio web actualmente \hcite{stack}. En la figura \ref{fig:topics} se puede observar un gráfico con los temas más comentados y una predicción sobre el crecimiento de los mismos. En estos temas no se encuentra sólo Python, sino también temas relacionados como los frameworks web Django y Flask o Pandas, NumPy y Matplotlib para data science.\\

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics [scale=0.3]{Images/topics.png}
    {\small {\it \caption{Proyecciión de tráfico para lenguajes de programación \label{fig:topics} \hcite{stack}}}}
\end{figure}

Además, por la simplicidad de su sintaxis y su curva de aprendizaje, se está comenzando a emplear como primer lenguaje de programación en carreras dentro del ámbito científico tales como ingenierías, matemáticas, biología, etc, desplazando al lenguaje más utilizado hasta el momento, Java. Como se puede ver la figura \ref{fig:pythonvsjava}, también elaborada por StackOverflow en el mismo estudio antes mencionado, el tráfico generado desde las universidades muestra cómo Python ha superado a Java hasta tal punto que tiene más del doble de visitas.\\

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics [scale=0.35]{Images/pythonvsjava.png}
    {\small {\it \caption{Tráfico generado desde universidades \label{fig:pythonvsjava} \hcite{stack}}}}
\end{figure}


\subsection{NumPy y Matplotlib}
Lorem ipsum

\subsection{PyCharm}
Lorem ipsum
```

As you can see, the first one should go right after "...Pandas, NumPy y Matplotlib para data science...". However, it shows before the paragraph starts. And the second image should go before numpy and matplotlib sections, but it is after those sections.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: The canonical answer for this question: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX tries to avoid placing diagrams in the flow of text. It is widely considered preferable to place diagrams either at the top of the page or at the bottom (or on its own page if it's big enough) and to call it out inline using a `\ref`.

You can give an optional argument to the `figure` environment to specify which behavior you want:

```
\begin{figure}[position]
    ...
\end{figure}
```

Where `position` is one or more of the following, in order of preference:

- `t`: Prefer placement at the top of the page.
- `b`: Prefer placement at the bottom of the page.
- `p`: Prefer placement on its own page.
- `h`: Prefer placement "here."

The `float` package gives you an additional option:

- `H`: *Require* placement "here."

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: better to say "allow" rather than "Prefer"  if you say `[t]` then latex will only allow top floats and will not place the float at any other position, unless all floats are flushed out with `\clearpage` (in which case the optional argument is ignored) also `h` is tried first if it is present so that should be first on your list.